# AdMob for Android: listener to click event

Tags: android, admob, onclicklistener, ads

I would like to detect when a user clicks on an AdMob banner.

I realized that most banners nowadays open only after a confirmation click.

AdMob provides `AdListener()` and its callback `onAdOpened()`, but such callback is not fired by the first click, it is only fired by the confirmation click which opens the ad.

Is there a way to detect the first click on the AdMob banner?

Answer (score 5):

Short answer is no.

Longer answer is not unless you want to get your account banned, as your only options to do exactly as youi have stated will involved inserting yourself between the user and the AdView which violates Admob policy.

Be happy with `onAdOpened()`

Comment: Thanks. It helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I think onAdOpened() is enough if you want to detect banner ad click, it invoked when user tap on ad.
What do you mean with "first click" and "confirmation click"? 
Whenever user click the ad it would open the ad and bring them somewhere (to play store or web page)

Comment: Thanks. It helped me.